# How to update a Textfield that has a value from an array of objects state variable in React?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, state

In react I am trying to update a rendered mapped array of objects in Textfields with the value set to the objects value and then also be able to update/change the value in the Textfield and corresponding state value.  Currently the array of objects is correctly being mapped and displayed with the objects value, however when trying to change the value within the TextField, nothing changes in the display and the console logs result in only changing the last letter of the value.  It seems as though because I need the Textfield to start with a value, that value keeps the old value due to the data being rendered with a map or whether I am updating an array of objects wrong?  Although in this example an array of objects is not needed, it applies to my component that does need it.

The following is some example code to demonstrate:

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';

const Test = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
      num: 1,
      name: 'hello'
    },
    {
      num: 2, 
      name: 'world'
    },
    {
      num: 3,
      name: 'test'
    },
  ]);

const handleChange = e => {
    const { name, value, id } = e.target;
    setData(data[id].name = value)
    console.log(value)
}

return (
    <div>
        {
          data.map((_itm, index) => (
            <TextField key={index} value={_itm.name} onChange={handleChange} name='name' id={index.toString()}/>
          ))
        }
      </div>
)
}
```

So 3 textfields will be displayed with the values, hello, world, and test.  When trying to edit the textfields, the values do not change.
Any and all help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the state hook, `data` is set to be an array. So you should always pass in an updated copy of that array whenever calling `setData`.

```
const handleChange = e => {
    const { value, id } = e.target;

    // Make a shallow copy of the current `data`.
    const newArray = [...data];

    // Update the changed item.
    newArray[id] = {
        ...newArray[id],
        name: value
    }

    // Call setData to update.
    setData(newArray);
    console.log(value);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and the code above didn't work. I did it a little differently and wrote a code that works 100%, no matter how you name the key in the object

```
const changeHandler = (e) => {
    const { id, name, value } = e.target
    const newArray = [...data]
    newArray[id][name] = value

    setForm(newArray)

}
```